# Power Query how to sum a cell of values separated by comma

Tags: powerquery

How can I turn this

| Staff | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 5,10,20 |
| Ben | 6 |
| Charles | 10,1 |

into this using POWER QUERY?

| Staff | Hours |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 35 |
| Ben | 6 |
| Charles | 11 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. Convert the source table to an Excel Table
2. Get data from that table
3. Divide the column by delimiter (comma) into rows
4. Change the column type to number
5. Group rows and sum the Hours column

---

**M code:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    DivideByDelimiter = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Hours", type text}}, "es-CO"), {{"Hours", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Hours"),
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(DivideByDelimiter,{{"Hours", type number}}),
    GroupRows = Table.Group(ChangeType, {"Staff"}, {{"Sum", each List.Sum([Hours]), type nullable number}})
in
    GroupRows
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this

1. right click the Hours column and replace values, replacing the comma with a +
2. right click Hours column and transform lowercase
3. In formula bar, replace the resulting formula so that it ends with

   , each Expression.Evaluate(_), type number}})

   instead of

   , Text.Lower, type text}})

Full sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Staff", type text}, {"Hours", type text}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",",","+",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Hours"}),
#"Lowercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"Hours", each Expression.Evaluate(_), type number}})
in #"Lowercased Text"
```